# How to use condition based on output value's not by individual fields

Tags: javascript, java

I'm retrieving 80 fields from my backend and shown in UI as table format as input type. but i got only data for 40 fields remaining hardcoded as 'NO INFO'.

I want put condition like readonly = true for where output = ' NO INFO' fields

this data get from database and shown as table format in HTML want to edit for only where data is available else readonly is true

Comment: If you show some of your code maybe someone will be able to help Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it in simple-to-read classic ASP to possibly get your thoughts moving...

```
If MyField = "NO INFO" Then
    strReadOnlyInfo = "readonly"
Else
    strReadOnlyInfo = ""
End If

<input type="text" name="MyField" size="20" maxlength="30" value="<%= MyField %>" <%= strReadOnlyInfo %>>
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, the issue is I can manage 1 field but here I have 40 fields, I think using 40 if conditions are not a good practice